# Global variable is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, global-variables

I have following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        var originalValue = $('#IndividualSystemSerialNumberCompanyId').val();
        $('#IndividualSystemSerialNumberCompanyId').change(function()
        {
            var main     = $(this);
            var newValue = main.val();

            $('#ChangeCompanyName').remove();

            if(originalValue != newValue)
            {
                console.log(originalValue);
                main.after('<span id="ChangeCompanyName" style="color:red;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Changing Company name will permanatly trasnfer IPC to changed company and old IPC record will be disabled.</span>');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

but above code is not working everytime is give me 2 in `console.log(originalValue)` i means it always execute `if` condition if i choose old selected value.

Do i need to define `var originalValue;` before?

Comment: I'm assuming it's also giving you 2 for the value of `newValue`. Have you checked to make sure your `<select>` element is structured correctly?

Comment: @jraede yes i have....and  and for `newValue` i am getting correct values..

Comment: You're telling me that when originalValue == newValue it still satisfies that conditional statement?

Comment: @jraede as you can see i am trying to store selected `option` value into `originalValue` and when `selectbox change` i am assigning changed `value` to `newValue` and then check for `condition` wheater both values are not same...if same then do nothing if `values` are different then show message,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the Help and have a look at my question but during developing Demo at jsfiddle i got it solved.

I have used below code and its working perfect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var originalValue;
    $(function()
    {
        originalValue = $('#IndividualSystemSerialNumberCompanyId').val();
        $('#IndividualSystemSerialNumberCompanyId').change(function()
        {
            var main     = $(this);
            var newValue = main.val();

            $('#ChangeCompanyName').remove();

            if(originalValue != newValue)
            {
                main.after('<span id="ChangeCompanyName" style="color:red;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Changing Company name will permanatly trasnfer IPC to changed company and old IPC record will be disabled.</span>');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

I have defined it outside of `document.ready` block and it has solved. May be because **fiddle do automatically call `document.ready`** so old code worked there but above change worked everywhere for me.

Again Thanks a lot to spend a time.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `originalValue` never get updated which is always equal to `2`, you need to assign new value to it in your `if` statement:

```
if(originalValue != newValue)
{
    console.log(originalValue);
    originalValue = newValue;          
    main.after('<span id="ChangeCompanyName" style="color:red;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Changing Company name will permanatly trasnfer IPC to changed company and old IPC record will be disabled.</span>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but you getting it all wrong...What i want is store page load selected `option` value to `originalValue` and when drop down `change` compare it with changed value and if then does not match show user a message...